# Importing the desk-clock android project into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I copied the code onto my computer via

> svn checkout http://desk-clock.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ desk-clock-read-only

into the folder `C:\Programming\desk-clock-read-only`

I try to create the project via File/New/Other/Android/Android Project from Existing Source.
I select the `C:\Programming\desk-clock-read-only` path.

For some reason eclipse only wants to import `C:\Programming\desk-clock-read-only\res`. 
The source files are in `C:\Programming\desk-clock-read-only` so they don't get imported.

There's just an empty src folder.

What do I have to do to import the project correctly?

Comment: Does it just look like it or is there really no src folder and manifest etc.?

Comment: Try to use "import general project" instead of android project I always have problems with this specific import way ^^

Comment: @Ahmad : The manifest is in the res folder and seems to be imported. There's an src folder but it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know how the developer of this project managed it to run this but usually the java files belong inside the src folder and the manifest definitely not inside the res folder. If you change this Eclipse(or the IDE of your preference) might recognize it, but you'll maybe get some errors because just putting the java files inside the src folder shouldn't solve it. You actually need a package. Check your manifest for that.